# Prove that the a bottleneck of path P is maximal

Tags: weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-trees

As the title says, the question is about finding the maximal bottleneck edge in path P.
Bottleneck of a path P in an undirected graph G = (V,E) is defined to be the weight of the edge with minimal weight on P. Given a graph G and s,t in V, find the path between s and t with the **maximal** bottleneck. In other words, find the bottleneck that has the maximum weight of all possible bottlenecks.

The algorithm is simple:

1. Find Maximal Spanning Tree T.
2. Return the path between s and t.

My question is how to prove that the bottleneck returned in this algorithm, or the path that contains the bottleneck is the maximal bottleneck of all other bottlenecks.

I need a formal proof of correctness. This is what I did:

- If there is only one path between s and t in the original graph G, then we returned the maximal bottleneck between s and t.
- If there are multiple paths between s and t:

Let $P$ be the path that contains the largest bottleneck from $s$ to $t$ in the original graph $G$, and let the largest bottleneck be edge $e$.
Assume by contradiction that $e$ is not in $T$. Let $e = (u,v)$, the vertices that e connects between. By our assumption, $e$ is not in $T. T$ is a spanning tree, thus $u,v \in T$. Thus, there is another edge $e' \in T$ such $e' = (u,v)$. If we add $e$ again to $T$, we will get a cycle and according to a theorem, all edges on the cycle are greater than $e$. But since $e$ is the greatest bottleneck this is a contradiction to how MST work.

Now, I know there is something wrong. Like, why can we even compare 'e' to other edges on the cycle. But, we assumed that P isn't in T, thus there must be a cycle in G somewhere between s and t, or a cycle that connects s and t in order to have more than one path between s and t in the original G.

I would appreciate if someone could navigate me or give me a full proof of correctness for this problem.

Also, besides the proof that e should be in T. We need to prove that what we found in the algorithm is actually the maximal.

I need help to continue the proof from here, given that I started it correctly.